# deep copy does not work, shallow copy works fine

Tags: angularjs

Would anyone know why the deep copy does not work in my case, the shallow copy/assignment works just fine:

```js
        vm.category = null;

        $http.get("/api/category/" + vm.categoryId)
            .then(function (response) {
                //does not work
                angular.copy(response.data, vm.category);
                //works just fine
                vm.category = response.data;
            }, function (error) {
                vm.errorMsg = "There was an error retrieving category data: " + error;
            });
```

This method for deep copy works fine:

```
vm.category = angular.copy(response.data);
```

why:

```
angular.copy(response.data, vm.category);
```

does not work?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a272a3c0bd88b6df354102dc059a0d14b5b22675/src/Angular.js#L811

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

> **angular.copy(source, [destination]);**
>   destination *(optional)* Destination into which the source is copied. If provided, must be of
>   the same type as source.

In `angular.copy(response.data, vm.category);` your source seems to be an array or an object, but the destination, `vm.category`, is neither an array or an object; it's null.

Try initializing `vm.category` to `[]` or `{}` - to match the type of `response.data`.